# SQL Server full-text search gets only one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

[image]

[image]

It only gets one value back is it possible to get multiple values inside? Like get test, test1 and test2.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Not my downvote, but posting images of technical information like code, sample data, or results, instead of formatted text, is the fasted way I've seen here for a question to downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at each of the three fully visible example rows:

- **ID=25** No match, because `IsDeleted` is `1`
- **ID=26** Match. This is the row you see in the results.
- **ID=27** *NO MATCH*, because `Contains()` matches full words by default. This means `test2` does not match the `Contains( 'test')` predicate.

Therefore the single row observed in the results is correct.

I know the full-words thing can surprise people, but it really is what you want more often then not. For example, if you search for `Contains( 'Kansas')` you don't usually want records for `Arkansas`.

Comment: You're also **very lucky** I'm answering this. I often don't see images in posts well enough to read the data.

Comment: I get that but is it possible to make it search more than one ? If not do you know any other good way to do so ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It'll search more than one if you write a predicate that matches more than one.